# Can't use the data I fetch from parse.com

Tags: json, parse-platform

I have created a simple program to illustrate my problem.

I have a custom class called TestDate which has 2 columns and the default columns one column is a string called val the is a date column called date.

I create a row and set 'date' to new Date('1st April 2013') and I set 'val' to 'First String'

Then I saved it and it saves ok.

Next I retrieve the row using fetch I am able to display the record in the  console window of the browser by using JSON.stringify(result)

If though I try to access specific values with JSON.stringify(result.results) I get undefined.

I have tried JSON.parse that hasn't worked I have also tried to access other data in the result object without any success.

It's as if the retrieved data has to converted somehow to be proper json but I do not know how? This is the problem.

my code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Date Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fetch()">Fetch</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
    (function() {
        Parse.initialize($PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, "$PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
            var TestDate = Parse.Object.extend("TestDate");
            var testDate = new TestDate();
            testDate.set({
                    'date': new Date('2013, 4, 1'),
                    'val': 'First String'
                }).save(null, {
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log("Inside create: success: result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                        // Result in browser console is:
                        // Inside create: success: result: 
                        // {"date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2013-03-31T23:00:00.000Z"},
                        // "val":"First String","objectId":"Nq2PmNH0yN",
                        // "createdAt":"2015-09-14T09:04:58.487Z",
                        // "updatedAt":"2015-09-14T09:04:58.487Z"}
                    },
                    error: function(obj, error) {
                        console.log("Inside create: error: obj: " + JSON.stringfify(obj) + 
                            " error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                });

    }());

    function fetch() {
        var TestDate = Parse.Object.extend("TestDate");
        var testDate = new TestDate();
        testDate.fetch({
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("Inside fetch: success: result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                // Result in browser console is:
                // Inside fetch: success: result: 
                // {"results":[{"createdAt":"2015-09-14T09:04:58.487Z",
                // "date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2013-03-31T23:00:00.000Z"},
                // "objectId":"Nq2PmNH0yN","updatedAt":"2015-09-14T09:04:58.487Z",
                // "val":"First String"}]}
                console.log("Inside fetch: success: result.results: " + JSON.stringify(result.results));
                // The result in the browser shows the problem I get back undefined:
                // Inside fetch: success: result.results: undefined
            },
            error: function(obj, error) {
                console.log("Inside fetch: error: obj" + JSON.stringify(obj) +
                        " error " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        })
    }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = result.get("date");
var val = result.get("val");
```

or

```
var date = result.attributes.date;
var val = result.attributes.val;
```

Comment: Thank you Arron Saunders for your help you were almost right. You at least pointed me in the right direction. 
It is actually: var results = result.get("results"); This makes results an array of objects so that the following can be used to display all the dates and temps.
result.get('results').forEach(function(result) {
     console.log("result.temp: " + result.temp + " result.date: " + result.date);
});